# eclipse workspace where to keep misc files

Tags: eclipse, workspace

This may seem like a strange question but can I add a folder in the eclipse workspace that doesn't get recognized by the system? Someplace to keep my notes and java files I'm not ready to including in the build yet?

I tried putting a directory my under src but ecplise tried to compile the files in there, I just want a place where I can keep stuff I don't want eclipse to look at

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try excluding a folder/files by:

1. Right-click a project folder in Project Explorer tree and then go to
   "Properties".
2. click on Resource and then go to "Resource Filters".
3. Add exclusion filters for files/folders .

[image]

Comment: its still complaining my java files in the excluded folders have errors. maybe i didn't do it right. anyhow, i just created a 'misc' folder at the project root and eclipse seem to ignore that